# Apache 2.4 SSI on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: apache-2.4, server-side-includes, ubuntu-13.04

I have an Ubuntu 13.04 server that had normal, stock Apache 2.2 with SSI working.  I got a bug in my ear, and installed the `ppa:rhardy/apache24x` PPA to get my server upgraded Apache 2.4.

While it wasn't a clean upgrade, I have gotten most of the kinks worked out.

However, I still can't figure out how to get Server-Side Includes working.  Everything looks ok, but when I hit one of my sites served from this server that uses SSI, it doesn't work.

I have `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/include.load` symlinked to `/etc/apache2/mods-available/include.load`

My site's config file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@myserver.com
    ServerName www.myserver.com
    ServerAlias myserver.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/myserver
    <Directory />
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +IncludesNOEXEC
        AllowOverride None
        XBitHack On
        AddType text/html .shtml
        AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Inside `/var/www/myserver`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mike mike  776 Feb 20  2012 index.shtml*
```

And the contents of the file start with an SSI:

```
<!--#include virtual="/include/header.html"-->
```

I have restarted the server after all configuration changes, and still don't have SSI working.  What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there is a difference in how Apache 2.2 handles `<Directory>` entries that align with `DocumentRoot` vs. how 2.4 does.

In 2.2, the following code:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/myserver
<Directory />
    [...]
</Directory>
```

would apply any of the directives (such as `Options` and `XBitHack`) to the `/var/www/myserver` directory and files therein.

In 2.4, the configuration needs to change to this:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/myserver
<Directory /var/www/myserver>
    [...]
</Directory>
```

and then `apache2ctl restart`, and then SSIs will work again.